# How to point to specific place of 2d array in this notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

how I can point to a specific row/column in 2d array? I want to get to a place where 8 is...

```js
 var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 0],
  [1, 4, 6],
  [6, 5, 8]
];

function test(column, row) {
  if (this.arrays[column][row] === 8) {
    console.log("yes !");
  } else {
      // more code....
  }
}
test(2,2);
```

so if I replace this

```
if (this.arrays[column][row] === 8)
```

with:

```
if (this.arrays[column][row] = [2][2])
```

this will not work.

Comment: It is `[row][column]`

Comment: And also use `===` instead of `=`

Comment: Depends on what your use case is. To check for known position can do `if(row === 2 && column === 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position is always set to that, in that array, I suggest this

```
var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 0],
  [1, 4, 6],
  [6, 5, 8]
];

function(column, row) {
    **if (this.arrays[column][row] === this.arrays[2][2]) {**
      console.log("yes !");
    } else {
        // more code....
    }
 }
```

Comment: @fernando why wouldn't it work? What error do you get? I'd like to help, but can't if your only comment is it won't work, because it would.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be `[row][column]` =D

```js
var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 0],
  [1, 4, 6],
  [6, 5, 8]
];

function f(column, row) {
    if (this.arrays[row][column] === 8) {
     return "yes !";
    } else {
        return "no"
    }
  }
  
  console.log(f(2,2))
```